# Create datetime with specific time mySql

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to create a date time field in a MySQL script that has a specific date and time.

I've tried using
`CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 DAY) ,'%Y%m%d'), ' 13:00:00')`
but it doesn't insert correctly.

How can I achieve this so that it will insert a date time with the time as above?

It inserts the record as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` with the above

Comment: It inserts the record as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: There are no `-` characters separating the year, month, and day parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql accepts datetime values in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format. In your formula you do not separate the year, month, day values, hance the result is not in the date format mysql expects the dates in. Change it to:

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 DAY) ,'%Y-%m-%d'), ' 13:00:00')
```

But I do not really understand why you need to do the formatting, just use `CURDATE()` function instead of the `NOW()`:

```
CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 9 DAY), ' 13:00:00')
```

Comment: Formatting wasn't correct, I've upvoted and marked as answer